# cx_freeze pyqt4 example ("\samples\PyQt4") doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, pyqt4, cx-freeze, python-3.3

My System:

Windows 7, x64, Python 3.3.1, PyQt4 4.10 using Installer (py3.3-Qt5.0.1-x64), cx_freeze 4.3.1 (win-amd64-py3.3)

What worked:

- Navigating in Terminal to the `..python33\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze\samples` folder (and into the respective example-folder) and execute `python setup.py build`
- This worked with: `\simple` and `\tkinter` (just to make sure I didn't went wrong somewhere else)

Problem:

- But my goal is to get a executable file/package of my PyQt4-Project, so I tried the same with the `\PyQt4` example (btw. the PyQt4app.py works perfectly as python application)
- `\PyQt4 >>> python setup.py build` doesn't work initially: Running the generated `PyQt4app.exe` results in an error, asking for the missing package "re"
- Subsequently I am including "re" in the `setup.py` file. (`options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : ["atexit", "re"]}}`)
- Now it generates an .exe without throwing an error - BUT running this .exe doesn't do anything, just silence...
- cx_freeze seems to find the correct dependencies: `python33.dll`, `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Gui.dll`, `PyQt4.QtCore.pyd`, `PyQt4.QtGui.pyd` (among others: sip, unicodedata, etc) are present.

Here the `setup.py` (unaltered, except "re" included & comments removed)

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
        name = "simple_PyQt4",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : ["atexit", "re"]}},
        executables = [Executable("PyQt4app.py", base = base)])
```

Any suggestions where I am going wrong? What additional information would be useful?

- btw. - [docs.python.org/3/faq](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-an-executable-from-a-python-script) links to **py2exe** - but py2exe **doesn't work with Python 3.x** !?

**edit:** I managed to get the console-output by setting `base = None` and running the .exe via a batch file. The Output is: `Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are:` (end of output - there is no list or anything).

So where and how to get this plugin loaded?

Comment: The `re` problem should be fixed by [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/18/ensure-re-module-is-copied-on-python-3).

Answer (score 4):

Ok - I found a workaround:

Copy the `qwindows.dll` WITH its folder `\platforms\qwindow.dll` from `..\python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins` into the folder where the .exe is. Now it works.

**edit:**

My `setup.py` looks now like this, and seems to be applicable to other cases as well:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = "Win32GUI"
path_platforms = ( "..\..\..\PyQt4\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll", "platforms\qwindows.dll" )
build_options = {"includes" : [ "re", "atexit" ], "include_files" : [ path_platforms ]}

setup(
    name = "simple_PyQt4",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
    options = {"build_exe" : build_options},
    executables = [Executable("PyQt4app.py", base = base)]
    )
```

Comment: It looks like platform plugins are new with Qt 5. I've filed an issue to handle them automatically: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/33/handle-qt-5-platform-plugins